# How to reply with attachment on Thunderbird using "with Attach" addon

Tags: thunderbird

Thunderbird 12.0.1, install addon - "with Attach 3.0"

below is quoted from https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/withattach/

As the author says, it will supply "reply with attachment" , but nothing found.

Is there someway else can satisfy this requirement?

> About this Add-on
>
> This extension adds a menu option (and a toolbar button) to compose an
>   email "with attachments".
>
> Also adds context menu options and toolbar buttons to "reply with
>   attachment" and "reply all with attachment".
>
> If you try to send the email without attachments, you are warned about
>   it and asked to confirm your action.
>
> Added option to scan messages for "attachment keywords". If the
>   message contains some of the user defined keywords and has no
>   attachments, you are warned about it.

another user says:

> expect the updates Rated 4 out of 5 stars
>
> by Rodger on October 9, 2011 · permalink
>
> As many other user raised the same requirement, I just want to
>   emphasize that: what we want is to reply the mail with original
>   attachment, without any more action. As now, it will only warn me if I
>   forget the attachment, if I wish to "reply with attachment".
>
> 4 star to encourage the update!

Comment: I would think that whomever sent you the email doesn't need you to email their attachments back to them. Often there's a "forward with attachments", for this particular reason. This might make sense in a group discussion, if someone was left out, but I would still be annoyed if someone emailed my attachment back to me.

Comment: @Thanatos i do think that there are use-cases where it makes sense to reply-with-original-attachment: eg i (as network administrator) am often receiving automated emails pointing to a problem with some info about the problem being attached and the "reply-to" address set to the remote administrative account. since the email is automated, the person behind the "reply-to" address might not be aware of my problem at all (usually the body of the email is very generic and does not allow to identify the specific problem). in general, it's a bad idea to pre-empt a user's decision by software

Comment: @umläute on that specific case, usually, a system administrator will have access to the core information the email was formed from and will not need the attachment which is client tailored.
I agree that software should be flexible and configurable, but sometimes you just want it to work without question and have to choose some behaviour. Also, remember that you always have the forward option.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the question, it seems that the add-on does work. It is just that you want a slightly different action to be done.

Upon reply, the new message is addressed to the same addressees that were addressed in the replied message, they all already have the attachment. Thus, there is no logical reason to send it again.

You can use the forward action to introduce the message with the attachment to a third party. In this way the new addressee will get the attachment with context.
You can also later reply to the original addressees with some informative contents letting them know you have forwarded the message. It will prevent unnecessary load on their message box and redundant network traffic.

Answer (score 1):

Workaround:

1. Install AttachExtraTools https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/thunderbird/addon/attachextratools/
2. Click on source message, then on attachments and right click: Copy all in the clipboard for new message
3. Click Reply to all, then in edit window: Attach -> Attachments from other messages
4. Write reply, send it!